# hide view created by layout inflater when navigationdrawer opens

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-maps-v2, layout-inflater

I have a screen with Google map showing up. I have added button on the map as `LayoutInflater`.

Here is the following code for it,

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.inflater_search_on_map, null);
LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    addContentView(convertView, layoutParams);
```

So with this code i am able to show certain `inflater_search_on_map` xml design on the map.

But the issue is i even have `NavigationDrawer` on the same activity so when i click on the `navigationdrawer` and as it opens up drawer the `convertview` which i customized will be shown on top of `navigationdrawer` so i was thinking can i hide that view or any other solutions do we have for this scenario.

Comment: Ya instead of programatically adding buttons i have put in xml file itself where i have a map fragment. That solved my issue.